# First display list according to HTML selection, then direct to particular page based on selection after clicking HTML button

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

[index page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/m6pUy.jpg)

First I am trying to list elements according to the option selected from drop down menu, then open a particular page related to a particular category after clicking Go To Related Page Button. For example if a user selects Fruits, then first it should list fruit items, then fruits.html page should be opened after clicking Go To Related Page button. Another example would be if a user selects Vegetables, then first it should list vegetable items, then vegetables.html page should be opened after clicking Go To Related Page button.

I have successfully accomplished first part, but stuck in second part. I have pasted my codes below. I was trying to accomplish second part with the help of a function named goToPage(), but don't know what to do. It does not have to be this function, any other way that would work are most welcome.

```js
// JavaScript
'use strict';

var category = ["Fruits", "Vegetables"];
var fruits = ["Apple", "Banana", "Orange"];
var fruitsLen = fruits.length; 
var vegetables = ["Cauliflower", "Brinjal", "Potato"];
var vegLen = vegetables.length; 

var i;
var listToDisplay = ""; 

//function to display contents accroding to the category selected
function displayContents(v){
  switch(v){
    case "fruits":
      for(i=0; i<fruitsLen; i++){
        listToDisplay += "<br>" + fruits[i];
      }
      document.getElementById('displayDiv').innerHTML = listToDisplay;
      break;
    case "vegetables":
      for(i=0; i<vegLen; i++){
        listToDisplay += "<br>" + vegetables[i];
      }
      document.getElementById('displayDiv').innerHTML = listToDisplay;
      break;
    default:
      document.getElementById('displayDiv').innerHTML = "Invalid Selection.";
  }
}

//function to go to particular page
function goToPage(){
 
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <script src="script.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

<div id="categoryDiv">
Select Category:
<select id="categorySelect" onChange="displayContents(this.value)">
 <option value="first">Please select a category</option>
  <option value="fruits">Fruits</option>
  <option value="vegetables">Vegetables</option>
</select>
<br>
</div>

<div id="displayDiv">

</div>

<div id="buttonDiv">
 <br>
 <input type="button" value="Go to Related Page" onclick="goToPage()">
</div>
  
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're very close, all you have to do is implement the clicking bit.  So, let's add a containing anchor tag (or link) for the button.  Then we can easily modify the `href` attribute.  A put up a couple dumby pages on my website so you can see how it works.

```js
// JavaScript
'use strict';

var category = ["Fruits", "Vegetables"];
var fruits = ["Apple", "Banana", "Orange"];
var fruitsLen = fruits.length; 
var vegetables = ["Cauliflower", "Brinjal", "Potato"];
var vegLen = vegetables.length; 

var fruitsUrl = "http://neil.computer/stack/fruits.html";
var vegetablesUrl = "http://neil.computer/stack/vegetables.html";

var i;
var listToDisplay = ""; 

//function to display contents accroding to the category selected
function displayContents(v){
  switch(v){
    case "fruits":
      for(i=0; i<fruitsLen; i++){
        listToDisplay += "<br>" + fruits[i];
      }
      document.getElementById('displayDiv').innerHTML = listToDisplay;
      $("#buttonDiv a").attr("href",fruitsUrl);
      break;
    case "vegetables":
      for(i=0; i<vegLen; i++){
        listToDisplay += "<br>" + vegetables[i];
      }
      document.getElementById('displayDiv').innerHTML = listToDisplay;
      $("#buttonDiv a").attr("href",vegetablesUrl);
      break;
    default:
      $("#buttonDiv a").attr("href","#");
      document.getElementById('displayDiv').innerHTML = "Invalid Selection.";
  }
}

//function to go to particular page
function goToPage(){
 
}
```

```css
#buttonDiv a {
  text-decoration:none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <script src="script.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

<div id="categoryDiv">
Select Category:
<select id="categorySelect" onChange="displayContents(this.value)">
 <option value="first">Please select a category</option>
  <option value="fruits">Fruits</option>
  <option value="vegetables">Vegetables</option>
</select>
<br>
</div>

<div id="displayDiv">

</div>

<div id="buttonDiv">
 <br>
 <a href="#"><input type="button" value="Go to Related Page" onclick="goToPage()"></a>
</div>
  
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: marked! Looks like we cannot mark only one answer as a solution.

Answer (score 0):

By this you can redirect to a desired page based on the selected option

Create two pages fruits.html and vegetables.html in the same directory

```
// JavaScript
'use strict';

var category = ["Fruits", "Vegetables"];
var fruits = ["Apple", "Banana", "Orange"];
var fruitsLen = fruits.length; 
var vegetables = ["Cauliflower", "Brinjal", "Potato"];
var vegLen = vegetables.length;
var optionSelected = "";       //Changed Here

var i;
var listToDisplay = ""; 

//function to display contents accroding to the category selected
function displayContents(v){
  listToDisplay = "";               // Changed Here
  optionSelected = v;               // Changed Here
  switch(v){
    case "fruits":
      for(i=0; i<fruitsLen; i++){
        listToDisplay += "<br>" + fruits[i];
      }
      document.getElementById('displayDiv').innerHTML = listToDisplay;
      break;
    case "vegetables":
      for(i=0; i<vegLen; i++){
        listToDisplay += "<br>" + vegetables[i];
      }
      document.getElementById('displayDiv').innerHTML = listToDisplay;
      break;
    default:
      document.getElementById('displayDiv').innerHTML = "Invalid Selection.";
  }
}

//function to go to particular page

function goToPage(){
    if(optionSelected === "fruits")              //Changed Here
        window.location = "fruits.html";
    else if(optionSelected === "vegetables")
        window.location = "vegetables.html";
}
```

HTML Code

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <script src="script.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

<div id="categoryDiv">
Select Category:
<select id="categorySelect" onChange="displayContents(this.value)">
    <option value="first">Please select a category</option>
  <option value="fruits">Fruits</option>
  <option value="vegetables">Vegetables</option>
</select>
<br>
</div>

<div id="displayDiv">

</div>

<div id="buttonDiv">
    <br>
    <input type="button" value="Go to Related Page" onclick="goToPage()">
</div>

</body>
</html>
```